# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls') at <Jasmine> in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, karma-jasmine, angular-test

When I run the test I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls')`.

Why I can't access controls in my test file?

My function:

```
describe('Login Component Integrated Test', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let loginSpy;
  function updateForm(userEmail, userPassword, organization) {
    fixture.componentInstance.loginForm.controls.username.setValue(userEmail);
    fixture.componentInstance.loginForm.controls.password.setValue(userPassword);
    fixture.componentInstance.loginForm.controls.organization.setValue(organization);
}
```

Comment: Try adding this line: `fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);`. Did you actually add value to `fixture`? As I see, there is only type for it, but no actual component...

Comment: After this I got this error:
"Error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test."

Comment: Try adding `async` on first line: `describe('Login Component Integrated Test', async() =>`

Comment: Thank You so Much. Now the issues are resolved.

Comment: I will post an answer to this since we got to the final solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as we discussed in the comments, you have to actually assign a value to `fixture`. You just annotated the type of it.
After that is done you have to add `async` keyword to the callback inside `describe`. Final working solution would look something like this:

```
describe('Login Component Integrated Test', async() => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
  let loginSpy;
  function updateForm(userEmail, userPassword, organization) {
    fixture.componentInstance.loginForm.controls.username.setValue(userEmail);
    fixture.componentInstance.loginForm.controls.password.setValue(userPassword);
    fixture.componentInstance.loginForm.controls.organization.setValue(organization);
  }
```